# jQuery live and sortable

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I have the following static html:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li id="li_10"><a href="10">Item 10</a></li>
    <li id="li_20"><a href="20">Item 20</a></li>
    <li id="li_30"><a href="30">Item 30</a></li>
    <li id="li_40"><a href="40">Item 40</a></li>
    <li id="li_50"><a href="50">Item 50</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have the following jQuery:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function() { 
        $("#mylist").sortable(
            {axis:"y"}
        );
    });
</script>
```

This works perfectly, but stops working as soon as I use jQuery/AJAX to generate the above HTML.  So I am assuming I need to use the "live" function in jQuery to do the sortable section.  Can someone help me implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is event based, so you can't use it for plugins like this. What you *can* easily do is call that code when your AJAX call finishes, for example:

```
$.ajax({
 //options...
  success: function(data) {
    //create UL
    $("#mylist").sortable({axis:"y"});
  }
});
```

The same goes for short forms of [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), for example:

```
$("#mylist").load("pageThatGivesTheLIElementGoodness.htm", function() {
  $(this).sortable({axis:"y"});
})
```