# How to apply jquery ui properties to dynamically created lists

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

So I have these nested lists that are created dynamically. An HTML list of sections, (each with an id of "section" + sectionNumber and then a nested list of items within each section. Sections are sortable between other sections, and items can be moved from section to section (via connected lists).

```
<ul id='sortableSections'>
    <ul>
        <li>Section 1</li>
        <ul id='section1items' class='connectedSortable'>
            <li>item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Section 2</li>
        <ul id='section2items' class='connectedSortable'>
            <li>item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

However, depending on the data pulled from my database there could varying amount of sections. So hardcoding each section id as sortable is out of the question.

So how would you go about (or what is the best practice) to make the sections sortable and their items connected via lists, dynamically? Essentially, I just want, regardless of the amount of sections, they all have the jquery ui sortable property applied to their items. How do I make that happen?

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323639/jquery-live-and-sortable  --  I think you need to implement `.live()` or `.delegate()`

Comment: Swatkins your link is contradictory to the advice you're offering, did you even read the solution in the link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('#sortableSections ul.connectedSortable') is the selector you need to use.  Binding them based on the class is better practise if you're using multiple items.  If you need to traverse each one you can loop like this:

```
$('#sortableSections ul.connectedSortable').each(function() { $(this).html('do something here'); });
```